# Why doesn't my CMOS inverter drive its output to ground?

Tags: mosfet, ltspice, inverter

I have created an inverter using cmos logic (see image)

[image: Inverter circuit]

However, when I simulate the circuit model, even without a load I get an output voltage that remains fairly high rather than going low (see image).

[image: Inverter waveform]

Any insight that anyone can provide with regards to my issue will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your PFET is "upside down" (source and drain erroneously interchanged) and you are probably getting a path through the body diode even when it is off.  Apparently in the device models you are using, the diode "defeats" the NFET.